# Using Include() in IQueryable times out even with LazyLoading disabled

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, lazy-loading, iqueryable

I have a 'parent' entity that links to other entities and when loading the list, it timed out because of all the connections, so I disabled LazyLoading.

It has been working fine, but now I need to retrieve a field from a child entity.  So I included the entity in the query with .Include() and it takes too long to load.

These are the entities. Coded is like a summary of the tree relationship created from the other classes.

```
public partial class Coded
{
    public int CodeId { get; set; }
    public int Maters_MaterId { get; set; }
    public int Levels_LevelId { get; set; }
    public virtual Mater mater { get; set; }
    public virtual Level level { get; set; }
    public virtual Sublevel sublevel { get; set; }
    ...
}

public partial class Mater
{
    public int MaterId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public partial class Level
{
    public int LevelId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public virtual Mater mater { get; set; }
}
```

When I do the following query, LazyLoading disabled, it works and works fast.

```
MyGrid mg = new MyGrid();
mg.codes = db.codes.Where(c => c.Maters_MaterId == 1 && c.Levels_LevelId == 1)
.ToList();
```

This one also:

```
MyGrid mg = new MyGrid();
mg.codes = db.codes.Where(c => c.Maters_MaterId == 1 && c.Levels_LevelId == 1)
.Include(c => c.mater)
.ToList();
```

But when I do this query, also with LazyLoading disabled, it steps-thru, but when it loads the page (view), it times out.

```
MyGrid mg = new MyGrid();
mg.codes = db.codes.Where(c => c.Maters_MaterId == 1 && c.Levels_LevelId == 1)
.Include(c => c.level)
.ToList();
```

In the Json script, I also have this, which is helping to clear out some errors I had before. I'm adding it in case it has something to do.:

```
var initialData = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model, new JsonSerializerSettings{ ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore} ))
```

Is it the way the virtual is loaded? Can I just load the fields I need? I'm using Json on the view, can it be how it reads?

Comment: please specify programming lanuage in tags

Comment: Why are you disabling lazy loading?

Comment: Can you verify that `mg.codes[0].level` is populated after stepping through that last code snippet? Can you use SQL Server Profiler to see whether additional database calls are being made while rendering the view? Is it possible that the view code itself has an infinite loop or something that's making it go slowly whenever there are `level`s present?

Comment: dont enable lazy loading.. if it's stepping thru this code then something else my be timing out.. `ToList()` enumerates the query so it's done.  I normally add `Include` before the `Where` though.. you might try that but i'm not sure that's your issue

Comment: If I don't disable LazyLoading it never even reaches the view. Codes is very big and with many relationships that go back and forth. The view seems to be calling on them.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to have `mater` in your view since it works when you include that part.

Try including both

```
MyGrid mg = new MyGrid();
mg.codes = db.codes
    .Include(c => c.mater)
    .Include(c => c.level)
    .Where(c => c.Maters_MaterId == 1 && c.Levels_LevelId == 1)
    .ToList();
```